# Empty Process Mail box in Erlang

Tags: erlang, message-passing

when you send a message to the shell process, you can flush all messages out by calling: [`c:flush().`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/c.html#flush-0)

```
C:\Windows\System32>erl
Eshell V5.9  (abort with ^G)
1> self() ! josh.
josh
2> self() ! me.
me
3> self() ! you.
you
4> flush().
Shell got josh
Shell got me
Shell got you
ok
5>
```

In my thinking , this empties the mail box of the shell process. 
What is the equivalent way of emptying the mailbox of any erlang process ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This function should flush all messages from mailbox (in any process where you call it):

```
flush() ->
        receive
                _ -> flush()
        after
                0 -> ok
        end.
```

Comment: Thanks @stemm. I am wondering: `after 0 -> ok ` doesn't it force the process out of the `receive` immediately ?  what is your reference for this, please ?

Comment: As I understood (and checked in practice) this function would receive all existing messages, while mailbox is not empty. I've read this tip in Francesco Cesarini book Erlang Programming (in 4th paragraph - about parallell programming)

Comment: Yes, the `after 0 ->` is guaranteed to try and match through all the messages in the mailbox before it "times out". It is more efficient than doing `after 1 ->` as no timer will actually be started; it is not needed.